# How to make webpack use multiple urls for publicPath config

Tags: cdn, webpack

I know in webpack you can set the publicPath to a cdn URL like so:

```
// Example CDN
output: {
    path: "/home/proj/cdn/assets/[hash]",
    publicPath: "http://cdn.example.com/assets/[hash]/"
}
```

but how do you accomplish the [trick of having multiple CDN aliases](http://cloudinary.com/blog/reduce_site_load_time_with_multiple_cdn_sub_domains) to improve load performance?

eg:

- http://cdn1.example.com
- http://cdn2.example.com
- http://cdn3.example.com
- http://cdn4.example.com

Comment: Have you managed to accomplish this just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think webpack supports that yet. I had a quick look at the source and it seems to expect a static value. You probably should [open an issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/new) unless you can find a matching one.

As a temporary hack you could try something a little clever. Set `publicPath` to something that's easy to replace. Then, using another script, detect those and perform replacement according to your logic. That might be a good workaround for now.